# Scheduling recurring task in ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, task, whenever

I have ruby on rails website,in which I want to perform some task at fixed interval such as 'sending report by email every sunday',for example.
I have examined using `whenever` gem but since it is wrapper for the *nix utility cron,it may not work on windows.

I am asking for which gem or method to use to do for scheduling such above task that is not depend on underlying platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [Clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) and [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) (optionally combined with [delayed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)) are good gems for scheduling tasks.

If you are on torquebox, it already provides a [job scheduler based on quartz.](http://torquebox.org/2x/builds/html-docs/scheduled-jobs.html)

Comment: I find rufus-scheduler fine and also according to [Ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/clockwork) , [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) is inactive

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebMin set up`. Set the Cron jobs for your application script that you want to execute and run it on the web min server `i.e your_ip_address:10000`. It is the best way for job scheduling. I used it in most of my project.